# To create a repository for 3rd party jars using Maven in Nexus

Tags: maven, pom.xml, nexus

I am new to Maven.

I need to create a repository in Nexus for all 3rd party jars used in our project. These 3rd party jars should be pushed to Nexus repository from the maven repository.

When compiling the java code the 3rd party jars should be downloaded to the .m2 folder (local repository) and the code should be complied.

Could you share the sample pom.xml?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding how things are working. Nexus can proxy the Central Repository and others. When configured correctly Maven will download all needed plugins and jar dependencies via Nexus into the local Maven repository and make them available on the classpath during the build as needed.

See more in the documentation. Esp check out the concepts and the Maven section:

- http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/concepts.html
- http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/config.html

You can also try it with the eval guide and the example projects.

- http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/eval.html

Comment: The dependencies (3rd party jars like log4j, commons-io) specified in the pom.xml will be downloaded to the local machine in $HOME/.m2 location, code will be complied and jar is generated. Now, these jars (for the first time) are moved to Nexus repo.

Comment: When a new project is again run with mvn clean deploy, first the dependencies in the pom.xml will checked in the $HOME/.m2 location, if the jars are not available then the jars are downloaded to local machine. Post the code is complied, the 3rd part jars that are not available in nexus will be pushed to Nexus along with the project jar.
Let me know if my understanding is correct?